# Can two PCIe endpoints communicate with each other through PCIe switch?

Tags: communication, pcie

[image]

Figure shows basic architecture of PCIe. From what I understood, **Root complex** block will convert data into PCIe format. That means PCIe endpoint to endpoint communication will happens through **Root complex** block.

Am I right ? If yes what is the purpose of Switch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PCIe is a packet switched network. The root complex provides access to system memory from the bus to facilitate DMA operations as well as providing a method for the CPU to initiate bus transactions. However, any device on a PCIe bus can initiate a transaction to any other device - the root complex does not have to be involved, except for setting up the address space on startup. The root complex generally contains a switch as well so that it can route PCIe traffic between its ports. Traffic between endpoints does not have to pass through the root complex if there is a shorter route through the switches. Extra switches can be added to provide more PCIe ports as the root complex can be a bit limited in terms of the number of ports it supports, and the root complex ports should be reserved for the highest bandwidth devices.

Comment: Suppose i have a SSD connected to a pcie slot. Memory devices use nvme. Will Pcie be responsible for converting messages from host message format to nvme message format and sending? Or will the memory device receive the pcie format message and reinterpret it as a nvme message further?

Comment: NVMe is PCIe.  No translation of any kind takes place, aside from maybe address translation in virtualized environments.  NVMe just defines the register space and what not so you can use a generic NVMe driver for all NVMe devices, similar to how all SATA devices have the same interface to the SATA controller.

Answer (score 1):

From the book [PCI Express Technology 3.0](https://www.mindshare.com/files/ebooks/PCI%20Express%20Technology%203.0.pdf):

> **Peer-to-Peer**
>
> If a device is capable of acting as a Bus Master, then
> another interesting option presents itself. One PCI Bus Master could
> initiate a transfer to another PCI device, with the result that the
> entire transaction remains local to the PCI bus and doesn’t involve
> any other system resources. Since this transaction takes place between
> devices that are considered peers in the system, it’s referred to as a
> peer‐to‐peer transaction. This has some obvious efficiencies because
> the rest of the system remains free to do other work. Nevertheless,
> it’s rarely used in prac‐ tice because the initiator and target don’t
> often use the same format for the data unless both are made by the
> same vendor. Consequently, the data usually must first be sent to
> memory where the CPU can reformat it before it is then trans‐ ferred
> to the target, defeating the goal of a peer‐to‐peer transfer.

So it may be possible, but rarely used.

Comment: Really depends. In high throughput applications we see things like GPUs directly fetching Rx buffers from the nic, or RDMA to and from storage devices, initiated by the NIC